# Symfony - Exception while trying to use ControllerResolver

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to use [ControllerResolver](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/create_framework/http_kernel_controller_resolver.html) to get Controller's class and doing some stuff within a `kernel.request` event listener but my code is throwing an exception when a Controller is represented as a Service (e.g. `fos_user.security.controller`). This happens on both Symfony 3.4 and 4.1.

So this is my code, nothing special..

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) return;
    $cr = new ControllerResolver();
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    $controller = $cr->getController($request);
    ...
}
```

and the exception is thrown as soon as I call `$cr->getController($request)`.

---

### Symfony 3.4

So I started play with debugger and I found out that exception is thrown in `ControllerResolver->createController($controller)`

```
protected function createController($controller)
{
    if (false === strpos($controller, '::')) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Unable to find controller "%s".', $controller));
    }
    ...
}
```

In fact a Controller can be found in `Request->attributes->get('_controller')` usually formatted as `Class::Function`:

> The getController() method relies on the same convention as the one we
>   have defined earlier: the _controller request attribute must contain
>   the controller associated with the Request. Besides the built-in PHP
>   callbacks, getController() also supports strings composed of a class
>   name followed by two colons and a method name as a valid callback,
>   like 'class::method'

However for some Controllers (like `FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController`) the relative Service ID is used (ie. `fos_user.security.controller`) and the `_controller` attribute is formatted differently using `Service:function` (note just one `:`). Therefore it's clear that an exception is going to be thrown in `createController()`.

---

### Symfony 4.1

Even if `ControllerResolver` class has a slightly different implementation on 4.1, an exception is thrown in the same situation. Actually in this version `_controller` attribute in Request is ALWAYS formatted as `Class::Function` even if the class is a Service ID:

```
// $class will be 'fos_user.security.controller'
list($class, $method) = explode('::', $controller, 2);

    try {
        return array($this->instantiateController($class), $method);
        ...
```

and then the exception is thrown there

```
protected function instantiateController($class)
{
    return new $class();
}
```

since doing `new fos_user.security.controller()` obviously leads to

> Attempted to load class "fos_user.security.controller" from the global
>   namespace. Did you forget a "use" statement?

---

Now it seems quite strange that nobody noticed this bug even because, according to documentation

> ...in Symfony, getController() is enhanced to support controllers as
>   services...

So am I missing something or this component really has bugs?

Comment: The obvious question is why are you using the controller resolver?  You can listen for the controller event and get the resolved controller from it.  And new'ing the controller resolver does not seem like a good idea.  It's not going to have access to the container so it's not going to work with controller services.

Comment: You might also try using the controller_resolver service.  But again, resolving the controller yourself while using the framework seem a bit strange.

Comment: And one more final note.  While you did not show the namespace, it is clear that you are not using the framework's controller resolver.

Comment: @Cerad thank you for your help. I didn't specify the `namespace` because I thought it was clear that I'm using the one specified on documentation (as you guessed). Moreover I agree with you: in this case `kernel.controller` event is more suitable. But I would like to know anyway why it didn't work. I'm using it just to get Controller's class and call some static functions. You can write an answer if you want..

Comment: Your best bet might to look at the actual component controller resolver source code.  It's reasonably readable and will make clear that the resolver has no knowledge of the container and thus cannot deal with services.  At the same time you can see exactly what it does support.